# Django ListView dynamic context data

Tags: django, listview, django-queryset

Given my models:

```
class Deck(models.Model):
   owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Flashcard(models.Model):
   owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   deck = models.ForeignKey(Deck, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   question = models.TextField()
   answer = models.TextField()
```

In my html template, I want to have a table of all the user's decks, each with their number of cards, e.g. like this:

Deck1:             15
Deck2:            22
Deck3:           100

In my views I have:

```
def get_context_data(self,**kwargs):
    context=super(generic.ListView,self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['number_decks']=Deck.objects.filter(owner=self.request.user).count
    context['number_cards']=Flashcard.objects.filter(owner=self.request.user,deck__name="Deck1").count
```

number_decks works as expected. 
number_cards also works when I manually type the name in. 
**But how can I do this without specifying the name**, so that in the html template I can just say:

```
{% for deck in deck_list %}
      <td>{{deck.name}}</td>
      <td>{{number_cards}}</td>
{% endfor %}
```

And since I won't know the names of the decks that users will create.

I've tried deck__id=deck.id, but I get zeroes.

How can I change either my models or views to get what I want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just write that as a function to your Deck-Model:

```
class Deck(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def count_flashcards(self):
       fc = Flashcard.objects.filter(deck=self).count()
       return fc
```

And in your template:

```
{% for deck in deck_list %}
  <td>{{deck.name}}</td>
  <td>{{deck.count_flashcards}}</td>
{% endfor %}
```

You might want to use a cached attribute decorator here as well